# What is the best way to generate and deploy Power BI datasets?

Tags: powerbi, ssas, ssas-tabular

We are currently using Vertipaq/DAX within SSAS Tabular.

We do generate our (complex) cubes through Powershell using some requirements held in a JSON definition of our own making.
We do this by modifying our base template created using Visual Studio and "exported" to an XMLA format.
The XMLA is modified by Powershell and the cube is then deployed to SSAS using the resulting XMLA.

We are planning to move our cubes to Power BI Datasets and thinking of using the same XMLA based approach, still holding our initial template in Visual Studio.

Does it sound as a reasonable approach with Power BI?

We know about Power BI (Desktop) Templates but they do not seem like an appropriate route if we want to automatically modify them before deployment...

Thanks

Comment: I'm surprised that this works. XMLA for our models has been a dumpster fire. Weird errors and all scripts fail. What types of things are you changing? Have you looked at Tabular Editor? It has some nice scripting capabilities. Here's a sample of building a model from a spreadsheet template and Tabular Editor script: https://github.com/m-kovalsky/ModelAutoBuild

Comment: We create our base complex cube in Visual Studio targeting a standard set of data with a relatively traditional Dimensional Model. Some of our measures are really complex. Then through XMLA, we do relatively simple things like changing the columns of our "Model dimension", we hide a few things if not relevant to our target dataset.

And so far so good.